# JMock Allow Other Method Calls

Tags: java, mocking, jmock

I'm using JMock to test the behavior of a class using an object. I want to test that the method `a()` is called. However, `b()` and `c()` also are called on the object too. Therefore if my expectations expect `a()`, it must also expect `b()` and `c()` to make the test pass. Is there a way to test only for a certain method, and allow anything else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Expect `a()` allow only methods `b()` & `c()`

```
mockery.checking(new Expectations() {{
    one(mockObject).a();

    allowing(mockObject).b();
    allowing(mockObject).c();
}});
```

Expect `a()` allow all other methods.

```
mockery.checking(new Expectations() {{
    one(mockObject).a();

    allowing(mockObject);
}});
```