# JMock - expecting oneOf() one method while allowing() all other methods

Tags: java, jmock

In jMock, is it possible to expect `oneOf()` some method while `allowing()` all other methods.

When I try to do this, the `allowing()` seems to override the `oneOf()` expectation and my test passes whether or not the method was called.

I only want the test to pass if the `oneOf()` method was called. I don't want to have to explicitly say `allowing()` on each method that I don't want to be called because that will clutter up the test.

UPDATE: I tried to write a little example to capture the essence of the problem and it worked, so it looks like I must have done something else wrong.

```
public class ExampleTest {

    @Rule public JUnitRuleMockery context = new JUnitRuleMockery();

    interface Callback {

        void method1();

        void method2();
    }

    @Test
    public void x() {
        final Callback callback = context.mock(Callback.class);

        context.checking(new Expectations(){{
            oneOf(callback).method1();
            allowing(callback);
        }});

//        callback.method1();
        callback.method2();
    }
}
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5370462/474189) seems to suggest it's quite possible and describes a solution exactly like you are trying. Can you post a minimal example that exhibits this behaviour? You could also try my preferred framework, Mockito, whose default behaviour is to allow all method calls :-)

Comment: Hmm, just wrote a little tester and it looks like I'm doing something else wrong. Thanks Duncan.

Comment: Ahhh, the power of the minimal example :-)  Good luck bug hunting.